# R extract rows with same ID that are most freqent per day

Tags: r, group-by, filtering

My dataset is rather large but looks like the following:

```
PData <- 

    ID      Date        Time    OBJ     Loc Condition  Color
    ID21    12/20/2020  04:52   rack    A1  Good       Bright
    ID21    12/20/2020  04:52   desk    A3  Good       Bright
    ID5     12/20/2020  12:05   rack    A1  Partial    Dark
    ID5     12/20/2020  12:05   desk    A2  Partial    Dark
    ID3     12/21/2020  03:25   rack    A1  Partial    Bright
    ID3     12/21/2020  03:25   rack    A3  Partial    Bright
    ID3     12/21/2020  03:25   rack    A5  Partial    Bright
    ID3     12/21/2020  03:25   rack    A4  Partial    Bright
    ID3     12/21/2020  03:25   rack    A1  Partial    Bright
    ID3     12/21/2020  03:25   rack    A2  Partial    Bright
    ID12    12/21/2020  09:25   chair   A3  Good       Bright
    ID12    12/21/2020  09:25   computerA1  Good       Bright
    ID34    12/21/2020  16:35   rack    A1  Good       Bright
    ID34    12/21/2020  16:35   computerA2  Good       Bright
    ID34    12/21/2020  16:35   chair   A3  Good       Bright
    ID34    12/21/2020  16:35   desk    A4  Good       Bright
    ID33    12/21/2020  10:36   desk    A5  Good       Bright
    ID33    12/21/2020  10:36   desk    A2  Good       Bright
    ID33    12/21/2020  10:36   desk    A1  Good       Bright
    ID33    12/21/2020  10:36   desk    A3  Good       Bright
    ID33    12/21/2020  10:36   desk    A3  Good       Bright
```

I am trying to filter based on various conditions and then extract the IDs that have the most entries per day.

```
 newDat <- PData %>%   group_by(Date,ID) %>%   filter(Condition == "Good", Color == "Bright") %>% add_count(ID)
```

I have the following code written so far, but I'm stuck on how to extract the rows with the ID that has the most entries per day.

Below is an example of what I am trying to achieve.

```
ID      Date        Time    OBJ     Loc Condition  Color
ID21    12/20/2020  04:52   rack    A1  Good       Bright
ID21    12/20/2020  04:52   desk    A3  Good       Bright
ID33    12/21/2020  10:36   desk    A5  Good       Bright
ID33    12/21/2020  10:36   desk    A2  Good       Bright
ID33    12/21/2020  10:36   desk    A1  Good       Bright
ID33    12/21/2020  10:36   desk    A3  Good       Bright
ID33    12/21/2020  10:36   desk    A3  Good       Bright
```

Any help would be most appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

We can `ungroup` and do a `filter` on the `max` of 'n'

```
library(dplyr)
PData %>%
      group_by(Date,ID) %>% 
      filter(Condition == "Good", Color == "Bright") %>%
      add_count(ID) %>%         
      group_by(Date) %>%
      filter(n == max(n)) %>%
      ungroup %>%
      select(-n)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 x 7
#  ID    Date       Time  OBJ   Loc   Condition Color 
#  <chr> <chr>      <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>     <chr> 
#1 ID21  12/20/2020 04:52 rack  A1    Good      Bright
#2 ID21  12/20/2020 04:52 desk  A3    Good      Bright
#3 ID33  12/21/2020 10:36 desk  A5    Good      Bright
#4 ID33  12/21/2020 10:36 desk  A2    Good      Bright
#5 ID33  12/21/2020 10:36 desk  A1    Good      Bright
#6 ID33  12/21/2020 10:36 desk  A3    Good      Bright
#7 ID33  12/21/2020 10:36 desk  A3    Good      Bright
```

#### data

```
PData <- structure(list(ID = c("ID21", "ID21", "ID5", "ID5", "ID3", "ID3", 
"ID3", "ID3", "ID3", "ID3", "ID12", "ID12", "ID34", "ID34", "ID34", 
"ID34", "ID33", "ID33", "ID33", "ID33", "ID33"), Date = c("12/20/2020", 
"12/20/2020", "12/20/2020", "12/20/2020", "12/21/2020", "12/21/2020", 
"12/21/2020", "12/21/2020", "12/21/2020", "12/21/2020", "12/21/2020", 
"12/21/2020", "12/21/2020", "12/21/2020", "12/21/2020", "12/21/2020", 
"12/21/2020", "12/21/2020", "12/21/2020", "12/21/2020", "12/21/2020"
), Time = c("04:52", "04:52", "12:05", "12:05", "03:25", "03:25", 
"03:25", "03:25", "03:25", "03:25", "09:25", "09:25", "16:35", 
"16:35", "16:35", "16:35", "10:36", "10:36", "10:36", "10:36", 
"10:36"), OBJ = c("rack", "desk", "rack", "desk", "rack", "rack", 
"rack", "rack", "rack", "rack", "chair", "computer", "rack", 
"computer", "chair", "desk", "desk", "desk", "desk", "desk", 
"desk"), Loc = c("A1", "A3", "A1", "A2", "A1", "A3", "A5", "A4", 
"A1", "A2", "A3", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A2", "A1", 
"A3", "A3"), Condition = c("Good", "Good", "Partial", "Partial", 
"Partial", "Partial", "Partial", "Partial", "Partial", "Partial", 
"Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", 
"Good", "Good", "Good"), Color = c("Bright", "Bright", "Dark", 
"Dark", "Bright", "Bright", "Bright", "Bright", "Bright", "Bright", 
"Bright", "Bright", "Bright", "Bright", "Bright", "Bright", "Bright", 
"Bright", "Bright", "Bright", "Bright")), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```

Comment: that works but only leaves me with the ID that has the max count. I need max count by day. So each day would have the rows associated with the ID that has the most entries per that day.

Comment: @Erika In that case, just replace the `ungroup` with `group_by(Date)`. Updated the post

Comment: @Erika can you check the output now